# SQL Server : search for table/column for a specific data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can you help me locate a for the table and column name for a specific value? See I only know the specific data but no idea where it resides.

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_which_i_don't_know_yet>
WHERE <column_name_which_i_don't_know_yet> = <value_that_i_know_of>
```

What I just found is look for a table with a specific column...

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%clientid%' 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this;

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = 'SearchTerm'

CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(370), ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        declare @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
        BEGIN
            print @query
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                @query
            )
        END
    END   
END

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```